# Team Foundation Server asking for Logon Credentials

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

Everytime I open VS2010 and or attempt to connect to Team Foundation Server it asks for my credentials.  I've done some extensive searching for this problem and its solutions (including this website) and none of the solutions work.  Upon attempting to connect to Team Foundation Server in VS2010 I get the following error:

"TF31003: Either you have not entered the necessary credentials or your user account does not have permission to connect to the Team Foundation Server at ...  Click the Use different credentials link below, or ask your server administrator to add the appropriate permissions to your account..."

I've done the follow:

Added a Windows Credential with the TFS Server name, user name, and password. Added logon credentials in "Stored User Names and Passwords" with the TFS Server name, user name, and password. Gone to the TFS Web Access URL, entered my logon credentials and clicked the remember my logon information (which stores it in "Stored User Names and Passwords"

So far, I can get into my TFS server via Internet Explorer without having to re-enter the logon credentials, but visual studio still keeps asking me for them.

I use Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate Edition on Windows 7.

Anyone have any other possible solutions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not entirely sure why you're getting the error, although I suspect there is a configuration issue on the machine hosting the TFS server. I'd verify that your user settings are correct.

As far as Visual Studio constantly asking your for credentials, I've had success with the method outlined in this blog post:

http://coolsubhash-tech.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-avoid-recurring-tfs-login-from.html

Make sure to add the domain part to the user as well as Visual Studio can be quite strict when it comes to these user names. If the domain is not there, you may see these issues.

Answer (score 7):

I had exactly the same problem and the [following link](http://blog.rthand.com/post/2011/08/26/Fixing-combination-of-NuGet-and-Team-Foundation-in-workgroup-configuration-401-Unauthorized.aspx) gave me the clues how to fix the damn thing.

1. You need to absolutely get rid of this abomination called "enchanced IE security". In 2008R2 this is done in server manager ("Configure IE ESC")
2. Go to IE and make sure your TFS server is in "local intranet" zone. If necessary, alter the defaults. I personally added my company's default domain (*.mycompany.local) to the list of intranet hosts. This also will help you with step 3
3. This step is crucial: many organizations put an alias to TFS server to point to something else, such as you are supposed to connect to tfs.mycompany.local, but really it goes to tfs99xyz50.domain.something.something.local. Easiest way to save creds for this kind of configuration is to open the TFS server URL in IE. IE will prompt you for creds and allow saving them, and you're done.

3a. If you are accessing TFS via proxy, also repeat the step 3 with proxy address.

Comment: +1 Simple :) Open internet options -> security tab ->Local Intranet zone ->Sites button ->Advanced ->Add the tfs url -> http://name-pc:8080  -> You might need to not Require server verification (https)

Answer (score 2):

What helped for me was to clear the IE cache and then connect to TFS again

Comment: simple, but highly effective!