# TFS 2017.1 web access broken

Tags: tfs

We recently upgraded from 2015.3 to 2017.1 and it stopped working. None of the users can get to web access. They get prompted for domain id and password which never works. No help or documentation is available to resolve this. We are AD controlled environment.

Comment: What URL are they attempting to access? Do normal source control functions work? Is SSL configured presently? Was SSL configured before?

Comment: What about other clients such as **Team Explorer** can you use to connect to TFS or not?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a great place to find help, but there so little information in your post that we can only guess between dozens of possibilities. IMHO you should open a Microsoft support ticket (if you have an MSDN license 5 are included IIRC) of hire a consultant to help troubleshooting what happened and focus the underlying problem.

Comment: nope. even Team Explorer is experiencing same bahavior i.e. prompting for credentials. Users are accessing same URL which they used to access before upgrade which is a friendly name. No SSL is configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by following instructions mentioned [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/33d15f68-0bd3-4997-9482-e2d9e7d88c9f/authentication-method-on-tfs-2017?forum=tfsadmin). The NTLM fallback is not working as prescribed by Microsoft [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2017/01/24/team-foundation-server-2017-and-kerberos-authentication/).

Answer (score 0):

The web portal is automatically installed and configured when you install or upgrade TFS.

First, quickly go through [What should I do if I can’t connect to TFS?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-r/ee523998?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Q%20&%20A) - a list of the most frequently encountered connection problems and what to do about them.

And since the username and password always get prompted for authentication, this maybe related to AD or IE settings, take a look at below similar issues:

- [Your TFS keeps asking you for credentials even with Active Directory](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2014/07/21/your-tfs-keeps-asking-you-for-credentials-even-with-active-directory/)
- [Team Foundation Server asking for Logon Credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924441/team-foundation-server-asking-for-logon-credentials)
- [Always prompted for credentials in TFS ?](https://nkdagility.com/always-prompted-for-credentials-in-tfs-2010/)

Comment: For more troubleshooting tips, go [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-r/ms244143).

Comment: Tried all the specified solutions with no luck.

Comment: @Sam Are you behind any proxy? If so, try to remove the proxy and also disable the firewalls on your TFS server and try again. Also clear IE cache on your client machine  to connect TFS site. Besides, did you got any related log info in TFS server logs or Even View which may help for narrowing  down the issue.